# One more limit with sum of reciprocals of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

It may be found interesting that the limit $$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left (\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{1}{{n \choose k}} \right)^n,$$ diverges when (i)  $N=n$, converges to different values when (ii) $N=n-1$ and  when (iii) $N=n-2$.Find $L$ in the last two cases.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I don't think case (i) is interesting at all. In this case $\sum_{k=0}^n 1/\binom{n}{k} \geq 2$ for all $n$, so of course when you raise it to the $n$th power it will diverge to $\infty$.

Comment: I have modified the question, you may please see it.

Comment: In find $e^2$ in case (ii), and $e$ in case (iii). The latter result applies also for other fixed  values of $N=n-m, m>1$

Comment: Yes, Dr. Hintze your are right. Thanks

Comment: But I derived the result not strictly but in a mixture of numerics and analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mbox{Let} ~~ S_N= \sum_{0}^N \frac{1}{n \choose k} ~ \mbox{then}~ L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(S_N)^n$$
Case (1): When $N=n$: $$ S_n=1+\frac{1}{n\choose 1}+\frac{1}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 3}+....+\frac{1}{n\choose k}+...+\frac{1}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 1}+1 \Rightarrow S_n > 2 \Rightarrow L= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^n= \infty ~ \mbox{(divergent)}.$$
This divergence has also been pointed out by kccu.

Case (ii): When $N=n-1$
$$S_{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{n\choose 1}+\frac{1}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 3}+....+\frac{1}{n\choose k}+...+\frac{1}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 1} \Rightarrow$$
$$S_{n-2}=1+\frac{2}{n\choose 1}+\frac{2}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 3}+\frac{1}{n\choose 4}+\frac{1}{n\choose 5}+...+\frac{1}{n\choose n-3}.$$
$$\Rightarrow 1+\frac{2}{n\choose 1} < S_{n-1}<1+\frac{2}{n\choose 1}+\frac{2}{n\choose 2}+(n-5)\frac{1}{n\choose 3},~~ \mbox{since}~~ {n\choose 3} \le {n \choose j}, \forall ~ j \le n-3. $$ 
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n\choose 1}\right)^n <\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (S_{n-1})^n < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n\choose 1}+\frac{2}{n\choose 2}+(n-5)\frac{1}{n\choose 3}\right)^n.$$ 
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n <\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (S_{n-1})^n < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{4}{n(n-1)}+\frac{6(n-5)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\right)^n.$$

$$\Rightarrow\exp\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n\left(1+\frac{2}{n}-1\right)\right)  < L <\exp \left(n \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{4}{n(n-1)}+\frac{6(n-5)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}-1 \right)\right).$$ 
 $\Rightarrow  e^2 < L< e^2,$ So by sandwich theorem $L=e^2$.

Case (iii) When $N=n-2$:
$$S_{n-2}=1+\frac{1}{n\choose 1}+\frac{2}{n\choose 2}+\frac{1}{n\choose 3}+\frac{1}{n\choose 4}+\frac{1}{n\choose 5}+...+\frac{1}{n\choose n-3}.$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n <\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (S_{n-2})^n < \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{4}{n(n-1)}+\frac{6(n-5)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}\right)^n.$$ 
$$\Rightarrow\exp\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}-1\right)\right)  < L <\exp \left(n \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{4}{n(n-1)}+\frac{6(n-5)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}-1 \right)\right).$$ 
$\Rightarrow e < L< e,$ so  $L$ in this case equals $e.$
As pointed by Dr. Hintze, for $N=n-m. m\ge 2$, it can be seen  here that $L=e.$